# Populate modal using ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, datatables

This is my controller file. I am using render function to create edit and delete button for each row. I am able to pass the employee ID in through render function.

I tried using the commented lines in OnEdit() it didn't work. I am trying to store data of the row in var data then I am passing the data in my $scope.Model which is defined on the top.

I don't know how to fetch the data of that passed ID. This is a table made using datatables.net. Please let me know how I should execute OnEdit and OnDelete function.

```
app.controller("postCtrl", function ($scope, tableAppService) {
    $scope.Model = {
        EmployeeID: "",
        Name: "",
        Age: "",
        Designation: "",
        Address: "",
        Salary:""
    }

    $scope.OnAdd = function () {
        $("#EmployeeModal").modal("show");
    };

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';

    var table = $("#employeeTable").DataTable({

        "ajax": {

            "url": "/api/Data",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                return json;
            }
        },
        "columnDefs":
            [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false
            }],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "EmployeeID", "visible": false, "searchable": false },
            { "data": "Name", title: "Name" },
            { "data": "Age", title: "Age" },
            { "data": "Designation", title: "Designation" },
            { "data": "Address", title: "Address" },
            { "data": "Salary", title: "Salary" },
            {
               
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-success text-white" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().OnEdit('+row.EmployeeID+')">Edit</button>';
                },
                orderable: false
            },
            {
               
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-danger text-white" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().OnDelete(' + row.EmployeeID + ')">Delete</button>';
                },
                orderable: false
            }
        ]

    });

    $scope.PostData = function () {
        tableAppService.postDetails($scope.Model)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });
    };

    $scope.OnEdit = function () {
        
        //var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();   
       // $scope.Model = data;
        $("#EmployeeModal").modal("show");
 
    };

    $scope.OnDelete = function (i) {
       
    };
});
```

Comment: when i am using only var data = table.row().data(); then i am able to edit the first element of the datatable. so its clear that i need to figure out the parameter inside it. table.row('parameter').data();  Can anyone help me to understand what parameter should be there